# Force "Replace" update behavior on changes to Metadata for AWS::EC2::Instance resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to force the "Replace" update behavior on changes to the Metadata property for AWS::EC2::Instance resources?

I have an EC2 instance that does not have any important state (so I don't care about its disks and other state getting deleted). The instance has a number of AWS::CloudFormation::Init scripts and files which are used to set up the instance upon creation. However, these scripts do not run again on update and nor would it make sense for them to run again on update.

The problem I am having is that sometimes I want to change something about the instance, which usually consists of modifying the AWS::CloudFormation::Init scripts and/or files. What I'd like to have happen is when I update the CloudFormation stack with a change to these Metadata properties, then I'd like the instance to be deleted and recreated (i.e. the "Replace" update behavior with `UpdateReplacePolicy: Delete`).

Here is what my resource looks like:

```yaml
  GatewayInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      # ...
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        # When this changes I want GatewayInstance to be deleted and recreated
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit of a hack, but I did find a solution.

Changing any of the following properties force replacement of the instance:

```
AvailabilityZone
CpuOptions
ElasticGpuSpecifications
ElasticInferenceAccelerators
EnclaveOptions
HibernationOptions
HostResourceGroupArn
ImageId
Ipv6AddressCount
Ipv6Addresses
KeyName
LaunchTemplate
LicenseSpecifications
NetworkInterfaces
PlacementGroupName
PrivateIpAddress
SecurityGroups
SubnetId
```

So, I simply created two identical key pairs and when I toggle `KeyName` between them and update the stack this forces the recreation of the physical resources. Et viola.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly its not possible as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/metadata-section-structure.html):

> During a stack update, you cannot update the Metadata section by itself. You can update it only when you include changes that add, modify, or delete resources.

You maybe could create your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to apply the changes that you make in `Metadata`.

The alternative is not use use `Metadata` at all.

Comment: Is there a way to force the replacement of an EC2 instance physical resource? I saw a recommendation somewhere on Stack Overflow to put a counter or a date/time in the UserData property and update it when you want to force an update, but changes in the UserData property only force an update not replacement. I don't see any other properties that could easily be used to force replacement when we change the init scripts in the EC2 instance resource.

Comment: @JoeCrivello It seems to me that your just pick a wrong tool for the job. CloudFormation clearly does not behave the way you want it.

Comment: CloudFormation is the wrong tool for deploying multiple identical EC2 instance resources from a template, within the context of many other AWS resources being deployed that depend on this EC2 instance resource? I'd be interested to hear what you think is a better tool for the job.

Comment: @JoeCrivello In your case, everything else is better. Terraform, CDK, Pulumi, or even just using AWS SDK. I already wrote what you have to do - create a custom resourse. If you don't want to do this, then don't use cloudformation. Using CFN consists of basically 80% writing custom resources to add missing functionality to CFN.

Comment: Actually I don't think a custom resource can even accomplish what I am trying to do, which is to trigger replacement of the instance resource. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @JoeCrivello Custom resource can do what ever you want, as you program entire logic for it. It can program replacement of any instance if you want.

Comment: Reimplementing AWS::EC2::Instance as a custom resource that does what AWS::EC2::Instance does but has the ability to force replacement as a counter is incremented seems like a lot of effort for a small amount of incremental functionality (unless there is some way to "sub-class" / reuse the functionality of AWS::EC2::Instance without reimplementing it completely).

Comment: @JoeCrivello Custom resource is the answer to your question. If you don't want to implement it, then you have to change your architecture or simply not use CloudFormation.